# Why is the protected method not visible?

Tags: java

Java experts, I would sincerely appreciate any insights!

I have an abstract class in a package with a protected method. I also have a subclass of this class in the same package. Now, when I try to instantiate the subclass from a class outside the package, and invoke the protected method on the subclass' instance, Eclipse is complaining the protected method is not visible.

I thought, protected methods will be visible to all children - in or out of the package - as long as the class visibility does not restrict it - in this case, both the parent and the child class are public. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

```
package X;
public abstract class Transformation {
  protected OutputSet genOutputSet (List list) {
    ..
  }
}
```

```
package X;
public class LookupTransformation extends Transformation {
}
```

```
package Y;
import X.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<field> fld_list = new ArrayList();
    ..
    LookupTransformation lkpCDC = new LookupTransformation();
    OutputSet o = lkpCDC.genOutputSet(fld_list); // Eclipse errors out here saying genOutputSet from the Type Transformation is not visible. WWWWWWWWHHHHHAAAATTTTTT????
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks all of you for the response. So in this case, are you saying I cant run genOutputSet from the class Test at all?

Comment: Additionally, the signatures don't match.

Comment: @BiAct - Hi, just updating whether or not you'd like to select an answer so that we may close this question off. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`protected` access means `genOutputSet` can be called by classes inheriting from the class where it's declared or by classes belonging to the same package. This means you can call it from within `LookupTransformation`.

However, you are trying to call it from an unrelated class - `Test` - located in a different package, which requires `public` access.

See additional explanation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: so I can do this -


public class newLookupTransformation extends LookupTransformation {
  ..
  OutputSet o = this.genOutputSet(list);
}
<br>
public class Test{
   newLookupTransformation nlkp = new newLookupTransformation();

}
<br>

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not in a subclass (you're in Test), and your code is not in the
same package (you're in Y). So the method is not visible. That's normal.

Answer (score 1):

`protected` means you may **call** the method in any derived class. However, `Test` isn't derived from `Transformation`. `genOutputSet` is only visible **inside** `Transformation` and `LookupTransformation`. This doesn't tell anything about the visibility of methods when they are called on an object of the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

The best possible answer I could give would be in the form of this picture that I used to learn it myself:

[image]

`Protected` methods work on subclasses(`inherited` classes in your case) that are in other `packages` aswell. You are however calling it from a different class(not `subclass`). Hope this helps!